# Accessing global variables from test file

Tags: python

I have a file A with 2 global variables

```
root = ""
crumbs = []


def read(line):
    global root, crumbs

    line = line.strip()
    open_tag = is_valid_open(line)
    kv = get_kv(line)

    if open_tag is not None:
        root += open_tag + "."
        print root                      <---------- prints stuff

    elif kv is not None:
        crumbs.append(kv[0] + "=" + kv[1])
        print crumbs                   <---------- prints stuff
```

I have a test from which I

```
from A import read, root, crumbs
```

I feed it some data

```
    read('<a>')
    read('<b>')
    read('<d>acceptor</d>')
```

And print the results

```
    print "." + root + "."             <---------- prints NOTHING
    print "." + str(crumbs) + "."      <---------- prints stuff
```

Why do I have access to the list but not String from my test file? Seems like if one works other one should work as well.

Comment: Plz show `open_tag` declaration and `kv` declaration

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj - updated

Comment: Are you sure open_tag does not get the value `None` for some reason when called from another file in the declaration?

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj. Yes 100% sure. Driven by the test, results are being printed in main code, but not in test. Additionally, same results are being printed for `crumb` in both places

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, it's because `+=` does different things for lists and strings.

- Strings are immutable. Therefore, `root += ...` in your *A.py* creates a new string and assigns it to `root`. There were two references to `root`: one in *A.py* and one in your test script. The `root +=` line changes only `root` in *A.py* since that's the only one that a function in *A.py* has access to. The `root` in your test module is not changed.
- Lists are mutable. Therefore, `crumbs +=` modifies the *existing* list, and doesn't change what `crumbs` points to. Since `crumbs` still refers to the same list in both *A.py* and in your test module, you see the change in your test module.

It becomes clearer if you write these statements without `+=`:

- `root = root + ...` obviously makes a new string and changes `root` to point to it
- `crumbs.extend(...)` obviously *does not* make a new list and does not change what `crumbs` points to

This little bit of confusion can arise when you try to access variables between modules without using fully qualified names. You end up with multiple names that initially (following the `import`) refer to the same object, but later something changes this.

The solution is just to `import A` and refer to `A.root` and `A.crumbs` in your test script. That way there is only one canonical name for those objects, and the names are "owned" by the module that changes them.

Comment: You didn't `import A` as the answer suggested you should.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great